# $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n) \hat \otimes_\pi \mathcal S(\mathbb R^m) \simeq \mathcal S(\mathbb R^{n+m})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

If $S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the Scwartz space of smooth rapidly decaying functions equipped with the topology generated by the family of semi-norms
$$\mathcal N_p (\varphi)= \sum_{|\alpha|, |\beta| \leq p} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n} |x^\alpha \partial^\beta \varphi (x) |\, ,$$
Is it true that $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n) \hat \otimes_\pi \mathcal S(\mathbb R^m)\simeq \mathcal S(\mathbb R^{n+m})$, where $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n) \hat \otimes_\pi \mathcal S(\mathbb R^m)$ is the completion of $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n) \otimes \mathcal S(\mathbb R^m)$ for the topology $\pi$ defined by the family of semi-norms 
$$\mathcal N_{p,q} (\varphi\otimes \psi)=\mathcal N_p(\varphi)\mathcal N_q (\psi)\, .$$

Comment: As in @PeterMichor's answer, the nuclearity means that _genuine_ tensor products exist, as opposed to the more typical situation that one can have one half or the other, but not both, of the characterizing properties of a tensor product. Some of the notes on my functional analysis page http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/ talk about the impossibility of having a "genuine" tensor product of Hilbert spaces, and also about nuclear Frechet spaces occuring as suitable (proj) limits of Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you understand the tensor product topology in the right way. 
Since the spaces are nuclear, inductive and projective tensor products coincide.
The result is theorem 51.6 of Treves: Topological vector spaces, distributions, and kernels.

## Added later:

Attention: The description of  seminorms on the tensor-product given in the question is not sufficient to specify a locally convex topology on the tensor product. There are many satisfying this description; all between the the projective one and the the inductive one and even more. See the source I have given, or many other books.

Comment: Thank you very much! The topology on the tensor product is then generated by the family of semi norms $\mathcal N_p$ defined above?

Comment: Grothendieck called the $\varepsilon$ tensor topology *injective*. The *inductive* topology is still finer and even for nuclear spaces it may be different from the injective one.